# Javascript plugin checking literal on Microsoft SQL

Tags: javascript

I am executing this javascript plugin to scan the log file.  It works great for Oracle, Sybase and UDB but not Microsoft SQL.  I am getting an error on the line var filename = line.split("\"); and the error is unterminated string literal (post-process#6) what do I have to specify for this literal in Microsoft SQLthe script is

```
properties.put("Status", "Success");
var process = [];
var filename3;
scanner.register("(?i)Executing",  function(lineNumber, line) {
var errors = properties.get("Executing");
var filename = line.split("\");
var filename2 = filename[16];
if (filename3 == null) {
filename3 = filename2;
}
else {
filename3 = filename3 + "\n" + filename2;
}
process.push(filename3);
properties.put("Processed_artifacts",filename3);
});
scanner.register("Fail", function(lineNumber, line) {
if (process.length > 1) {
process.reverse(); 
var element1 = process[1];
properties.put("Processed_artifacts",element1);
}
if (process.length < 2) {
var element1 = 'default.txt';
properties.put("Processed_artifacts",element1);
}
properties.put("exitCode", "1");
properties.put("Status", "Fail");
var value = line.replace("Fail ", "")
properties.put("Fail", value);
});
scanner.scan();
var errors = properties.get("Fail");
if (errors == null) {
errors = new java.util.ArrayList();
}
properties.put("Error", errors.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a single backslash, you have to use `\\`:

```
var filename = line.split("\\");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2yfce773%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: Tried that and it removed the error but the input is Executing : c:\program files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd -b -S sasqld01 -U sraoper -P **** -d model -i C:\Serena\ReleaseAutomationAgent\core\var\work\ABS_SQL\sqlserve_abs_sq00045.sql and it does not pick up the \ using the \\